# Set Multi-Index DataFrame values for each inner DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a (very) large multi-indexed dataframe with a single boolean column. for example:

```
bool_arr = np.random.randn(30)<0
df = pd.concat(3*[pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=['A','B','C'])],
           keys=np.array(['one', 'two', 'three']))
df['bool'] = bool_arr
df.index.rename(['Ind1', 'Ind2'], inplace=True)
```

I'm trying to set the boolean column to False on the 2 first & 2 last indices of each inner dataframe, but only if the 3rd (or 3rd to last) isn't True. Meaning, I want the first and last 3 boolean entries to be the same.

I can do this by iterating over each index-level, extracting the inner dataframes one by one and resetting the relevant values, then plugging the new Series back to a copy of the original dataframe. But this is **very** wasteful in both time & memory.
Is there a faster way of doing this?
(I should add that in my example all inner dataframes are of the same length, but that's not necessarily the case for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `groupby.transform` the 'bool' column to get the third value with [`nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html), then get the [`intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) with the index of the first two elements with `head` (last 2 elements `tail`) per group as well. Then, you can `loc` the [`union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) of index to be set to `False`:

```
# used per group action several times
gr = df.groupby(level=0)

# get the third value per group
s1 = gr['bool'].transform('nth',2)
# intersection of index with False at 3rd position per group 
# and index of first 2 rows per group
index_head = df.index[~s1].intersection(gr.head(2).index)

# get the last third value per group
s2 = gr['bool'].transform('nth', -3) #note -3 and not -2
# same idea but with tail
index_tail = df.index[~s2].intersection(gr.tail(2).index)

# loc the union of all the index to change
df.loc[index_head.union(index_tail), 'bool'] = False
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm guessing that for index_tail you meant to write gr.tail().